# Get a value from array_keys

Tags: php

maybe a simple question but I can't figure it out.. 
I try to put values from an array in a variable, but it doesn't seem to work.

> $array = array(0 => 100, "color" => "red");
>
> print_r(array_keys($array));

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => color
)
```

Then why can't I say:

> print_r(array_keys($array[1]));

So it will output: `color`

How do I put `color` in a variable?

*** Update: I work in PHP 5.3, unfortunately

> print_r(array_keys($array)[1]);

don't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `$array[1]` is the key `1` of `$array`. If you use PHP 5.4+ you can do this directely:

```
print_r(array_keys($array)[1]);
```

[**DEMO**](http://3v4l.org/TrOGV)

Otherwise you have to save it a variable first:

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
print_r($keys[1]);
```

[**DEMO**](http://3v4l.org/GDJDM)

[Manual entry for array deferencing in 5.4+](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-89):

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.

Comment: It's a string, so instead of `print_r()`, you can `echo` it :)

Comment: @AmalMurali You're right - this was only to copy OP's way of doing it. :) I feel that the less we change in our answers, the more the OP understands the change.

Comment: @Ruub Can you update your OP with the second example? You can't use the first way, as that **requires** 5.4+.

Comment: @Ruub Your second piece of code should work perfectly, and if it doesn't you've probably done something wrong somewhere else in your code. As shown [here](http://3v4l.org/GDJDM) it works fine. If you copy paste that code, it works fine, right? Can you create an example on 3v4l, codepad, etc., where the second example fails with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:

```
print_r(array_keys($array)[1]);
// -----------------------^^^ After array_keys()
```

Answer (score 0):

because of `$array[1]` is not an array. it has just a string value.

`array_keys` functions indentify only the arrays, can not the strings key.

If the `$array[1]` have an array then it will return an array with values of keys.